# memory leaks issues in ios/objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks, clang-static-analyzer

i am developing the ios app and now want to test it for memory leaks, i have used the

> clang static analyzer

and its giving me this bug report

```
-(void)pass
{
printf("reading plist info");   
// Path to the plist (in the application bundle)
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:
                  @"sortednames" ofType:@"plist"];

// Build the array from the plist  
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

for (id key in dict) {
    NSLog(@"bundle: key=%@, value=%@", key, [dict objectForKey:key]);
    string_values=[dict objectForKey:key];
    //NSLog(@"bundle data: key=%@, value=%@", key, [string_values objectAtIndex:0]);
}
//[dict release];
}
```

the info provided by analyzer is
[image: whst i do now???]

and one things more
is it enough for memory management for my app ????
or i have to do some more tasks ???
thanks for replies

Comment: why did you uncomment `[dict release];` ?

Comment: when i uncomment it >> the app crashes and can't proceed further

Comment: Use `autorelease`. 
`NSDictionary *dict = [[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path] autorelease];`

Comment: Assuming this is not ARC you need the release.  But you assign a value to `string_values`, apparently some sort of global, and that value is probably not being properly retained.  (`autorelease` won't help, except maybe by accident.)

Comment: can you use directly method dictionaryWithContentsOfFile? that i have answered. Check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string_values = [[dict objectForKey:key] **retain**];
```

You should synthetise a strong / retain property and assign your ivar via self.string_values.
You can then release your dictionnary and string_value will still be valid.

```
...
@property(nonatomic, retain)NSString* string_value;
...
@synthetyse string_value;
...
```

then

```
self.string_values = [dict objectForKey:key];
```

And no, static analyzer is not a bullet proof for memory leaks. It can find algorythmically a leaks on compute time, but not those on runtime. That's why it's called **static** analyzer.
But it's really helpful by the way!

You can then profile your apps and use the leaks tool in order to check others leaks.

Comment: then where to release the string_values

Comment: since string_values is an ivar or global var (I don't know where you declared it into your code), release it when you don't need it anymore, or simply into your dealloc method.

Answer (score -1):

You can use directly NSDictionary's object. No need to allocate. You can use like this way.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:
                  @"sortednames" ofType:@"plist"];

dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: 
                         path];
```

Comment: autorelease or static allocation won't change the problem. Problem is the string assigment into a future garbage value. (aka dangling pointer)